# JQuery UI Dialog buttonpane div appendTo form

Tags: jquery, forms, button, dialog, append

I want to append the panel that is created for the buttons in the dialog. So i can access controls in the form with the Print button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dialogDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        position: [50, 50],
        buttons: {
            "Print": function() {
                //Do stuff
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $(".dialogDiv").parent().appendTo($('form'));
});

<div class="dialogDiv" title="Printwindow"> ... Controls n stuff</div>
```

There is a auto-generated div for the buttons and in firebug there is a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
```

The question is then how do i append that to the form also?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you just need to do 

      $('div.ui-dialog-buttonpane').appendTo($('form'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately @TommyB's solution (in the question's comment) won't work if there are multiple dialogs on a page.

Instead, do this:

```
$("#mydialog").siblings(".ui-dialog-buttonpane")
```